# onFocusChange called multiple times results in "hasFocus" variable to be unusable

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, listener

I have two `EditText` widgets and want to hide the keyboard when the user clicks outside of those (if the keyboard is still active at that time obviously).
To do this I am using a `setOnFocusChangeListener` on both of them like so :

```java
eTNom=convertView.findViewById(R.id.EditText_nom);

eTNom.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) 
            hideKeyboard(v);
    }
});
```

The other `setOnFocusChangeListener` is handled exactly the same way.

However this does not work because the onFocusChange method is called multiple times (4-5) every time I click on one of the two `EditText`. This results in the `hasFocus` variable switching between true and false rapidly after the method is called and the keyboard only shows up for a very brief moment.

Here's exactly what's happening : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGy1C.jpg

I have seen this question asked once but the accepted answer suggested to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the manifest file. I did that but it did not solve my problem. I also saw people recommending to set the *clickable*, *focusable* and *focusableInTouchMode* attributes to `true` in the parent layout, which I also did, but it still does not work.

I thought that the problem came from the fact that I have two `EditText` widgets but when I deleted one from my activity I still had the same problem so I am pretty much lost right now and any sort of help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put below lines in Menifest

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

OR you can show/hide the keyboard by using below two  functions

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
       InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

 /* Shows the soft keyboard */
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    view.requestFocus();
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
```

}

Comment: Simply adding the ```if``` in my ```hideKeyboard()``` method did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apply this way:

```
etTextInput.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    etTextInput.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                    etTextInput.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                } else {
                    etTextInput.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                }
            });
```